# CSV import with Autocomplete

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a csv file I want to import, but I want to know if it is possible to do an autocomplete based on text in other columns.

For example: If column 2 has Basic listed, column B should give a cost of $2.

I have this doing it via jquery on the data entry form, but wanted to see if this is possible for previous files done before we switched over to the DB.

A reference would be great, that I could read upon.  Thanks

Comment: Are these values stored in a mySQL database?

Comment: They can be, I would just not know the structure.  For the data entry screen, they are stored in a jquery .js file